# AngularJS populate modal with data with click

Tags: angularjs, modal-dialog

new to angularjs. ive got a list of players. What i want to do is when click on a player I want to be able to create an overlay modal with that specific players details. I think i have to use a directive but not sure how I can populate the modal with the correct player data...

If any one can point me the right direction that would be great..

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming you wanted this,

**In controller:**

```
$scope.players = [{name: 'sss'}, {name: 'aaa'}];          //array of players

$scope.select = function (index) {
    $scope.selectedPlayer = $scope.players[index];
}
```

**In template:**

```
<div ng-repeat='player in players'>
    <div ng-click='select($index)'>{{player.name}}</div>
</div>
```

When you click on the player in the view you will get the player object in `$scope.selectedPlayer` modal

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [angular-ui/ui-bootstrap](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/).

It has a lot of the DOM manipulating components you are used to working with between **JQueryUI** and **Twitter bootstrap** already created as directives (including modals).